# Ffmpeg first creates the watermark and then creates the text

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark

My code:

```
ffmpeg -y -i tt.mp4 -i qmy.png -filter_complex "[1:v]  
overlay=100:100:enable='if(gt(t,5),lt(t,10))'[img];[img][0:v]
drawtext=text='test':fontfile=PingFang-SC-
Regular.ttf:fontcolor=#FFFFFF:fontsize=36:x=120:y=120:enable='if(gt(t,5),lt
(t,10))'[out]" -map "[out]" out.mp4
```

[image]

Comment: [AVFilterGraph @ 0x7fd080602c00] Too many inputs specified for the "drawtext" filter.
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument

Comment: The command is malformed. What do you need to do?